# Playing default sounds

Tags: android

Is is possible to play the keyboard default sound without knowing the Android Version or the path to the sound.

The sound seems to change depending on the version of Android being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void PlayKeyPress (Context c){
    AudioManager am=(AudioManager) c.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD, (float) 0.5);
}
```